# Python GUI with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I have a problem with a gui in python, the program executes the command option from the button creation automatic. so i get stuck in a loop.
'''
    Created on 5-mrt.-2012

```
@author: Max
'''
from Tkinter import *


class main(Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.mainWindow()
    def mainWindow(self):
        '''Make the main window '''
        self.quitAll()
        self.app = Tk()
        self.app.title('NMBS application')
        self.makeAppButtons()
        self.finish(self.app)
    def makeAppButtons(self):
        '''Make all the buttons for the main menu'''
        button_lijn = Button(self.app, text="Voeg lijnritten toe", command = self.lijnritten())
        button_lijn.pack()
    def finish(self,window):
        ''' Make the main window'''
        window.mainloop()
    def endButton(self,window):
        '''Make a quit button'''
        button_back = Button(window,text="Sluiten",command = self.mainWindow())
        button_back.pack()
    def quitAll(self):
        '''Close all the current windows'''
        self.lijn_window.quit()
        self.app.quit()
    def lijnritten(self):
        ''' Make the lijnritten window'''
        self.app.quit()
        self.lijn_window = Tk()
        self.lijn_window.title("lijnritten")
        self.endButton(self.lijn_window)
        self.finish(self.lijn_window)
main(None)
```

Comment: you know you can do single line comments like `# so` - instead of `''' comment '''` ?

Comment: @Alex, he's doing it right. Strings in that position become the function's help text ("docstring").

Comment: @alexis - ah, right - did not know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link the commands, do it without the () so `command=self.action`, like this. Also this line seems to be giving you some trouble `self.quitAll()`... not sure what your trying to do with it but that's my two cents.

```
''' 
Created on 5-mrt.-2012
@author: Max
'''
from Tkinter import *


class main(Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.mainWindow()
    def mainWindow(self):
        '''Make the main window '''
        #self.quitAll()
        self.app = Tk()
        self.app.title('NMBS application')
        self.makeAppButtons()
        self.finish(self.app)
    def makeAppButtons(self):
        '''Make all the buttons for the main menu'''
        button_lijn = Button(self.app, text="Voeg lijnritten toe", command = self.lijnritten)
        button_lijn.pack()
    def finish(self,window):
        ''' Make the main window'''
        window.mainloop()
    def endButton(self,window):
        '''Make a quit button'''
        button_back = Button(window,text="Sluiten",command = self.mainWindow)
        button_back.pack()
    def quitAll(self):
        '''Close all the current windows'''
        self.lijn_window.quit()
        self.app.quit()
    def lijnritten(self):
        ''' Make the lijnritten window'''
        self.app.quit()
        self.lijn_window = Tk()
        self.lijn_window.title("lijnritten")
        self.endButton(self.lijn_window)
        self.finish(self.lijn_window)
main(None)
```